# VSCode extension Git Graph on HTTPS repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using Git Graph with VSCode, on a repository that can only be used with HTTPS protocol (for now, the admins are still working on making SSH possible)

When I do local checkout, there is no problem. However, when I try to fetch or push to the remote using Git Graph, I have the following error:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for <repo url here>
error: Could not fetch origin
Fetching origin
```

So, for those operations, I have to use the command line (which succesfully prompts me to enter my password)

Is there any configuration in the Git Graph extension that could allow HTTPS usage within the extension?